# Magento: Loading attributes for a product programmatically - How?

Tags: magento, collections, attributes, load, product

Pardon if this has been asked before. I have found several posts about loading attributes but I haven't been able to load the ones I need based on what I've read.

I'm trying to create a select box to display the values of a custom attribute on a page that lives within the app but does not belong to it (just a custom PHP product display page). I know I'm close, I just don't know what is the proper method to call for this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
                            ->setCodeFilter('color_attribute')
                            ->getFirstItem();
```

If I print $attributeInfo I get an array with the attribute info but I am at a loss as to how to display ONLY the name and value of the color_attribute that applies to the current product only.

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($attributeInfo->getData()); echo "</pre>";
```

Basically, I want to load all of the "color_attribute"s that apply to a particular product in a select box. That way the user can view a product and select its color by selecting the color from the select.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to work with the attribute config.

```
/* @var $attr Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */
$entityType = 'catalog_product';
$attrCode   = 'some_attr';
$attr = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute($entityType,$attrCode);

var_dump($attr->getSource()->getAllOptions());
```

Comment: Brilliant! That got me what I needed. Thanks, Ben!